# WiX properties ignored when put in separate file

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I have a WiX install project.

I put my properties into a separate file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <Property Id="PORT" Value="60010" />
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I want to use it in my file with dialogs like this:

```
<Dialog Id="ConfigurationDlgUraniaService" Width="370" Height="270" Title="Title">
     <Control Type="Edit" Id="Port" Width="100" Height="15" X="120" Y="60" Text="60000" Property="PORT" Integer="yes" />
</Dialog>
```

The `Text="60000"` is not shown and the property value of 60010 is not shown.

If I add this in the `DialogFile` :

```
 <SetProperty Id="PORT" Value="60010" After="AppSearch" />
```

then it works. But I don't want to reset the variables.

Is it not possible to put the variables into a separate file?

Best regards
Linus

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of options:

I. **[Preferred]** Define your properties in the `wxi` (include) file and then include it into the main `wxs` authoring:

The include file (`Properties.wxi`) might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Include>
  <Property Id="PORT" Value="60010" />
</Include>
```

And then you include it into `DialogFile.wxs`:

```
<?include Properties.wxi?>
```

II. *Alternative*. Reference any of the properties defined in the separate `wxs` file from the main `DialogFile.wxs` in order to include the entire fragment.

In this case, your separate `wxs` file containing properties remains as is, and in the `DialogFile.wxs` you author this element (it can be any property defined in that file, and just one is enough):

```
<PropertyRef Id="PORT"/>
```

This action will instruct WiX to include the entire parent fragment of the PORT property.

The first approach looks more intuitive in this case.

Comment: I get a compile error when declare <Property> under <Include> container. This doesn't work for me. Am I missing something?

Comment: `<Include>` is just a top-level container and can have children of any type: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/include.html. Make sure the file it resides in is .wxi, and it is included in .wxs.

Comment: Below is the content of the WXI include file where I define one property:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Include>
    <Property Id="Test_PROP" Value="TEST_VALUE" />
</Include>


And then in the main WXS file I include that WXI file:

<?include IncludeTEST.wxi?>

and I still get that error.

Comment: The error simply says: 

The Wix element contains an unexpected child element 'Property'.

Comment: I think it matters where you `<?include ...?>` your wxi file then in the main wxs. As long as wxi contains the definition of the property, when it is included it should end up under one of its allowed parents, e.g. `<Fragment>` or `<Product>`.

Comment: The WixToolset website says that <?include?> has no parents. However, when I tried to put the <?include?> under <product> then it worked for me (I had it before <product> so far, which works fine if the wxi file has variable definitions only, but no properties). Note, one shall have <?include?> after <package> in the <product>! Thanks @Yan Sklyarenko.